# qgz-projects can't be opened in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, windows-7, qgz

I have recently switched to QGIS 3.4.0 and currently, I can't open projects saved in `.qgz`-format.

No error message, no crash, they simply don't open.

When I try to load the project a second time, I get a small tooltip at the bottom of the window "Project Loaded" - though that definitely is not the case.

On the other hand, `.qgs`-files can be opened without any hassle.

Is this a known error, maybe already solved?

Comment: what operating system are you running?

Comment: Running on Win 7 64bit.

Comment: apparently it is a permission problem, which is still not solved.(win7 64bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running win 10 64 bit. Had the same problem.
Problem solved in QGIS 3.6